# .Net Core 3.1 Multi-Language Localization

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, localization

I am writing and the terminology varies by state.  So I am looking to try to get this to work with Resx because the reporting tool we bought Telerik uses resx for multi language support.

What I was hoping to do was label the SharedResource.en-US-TX.resx tacking on the TX at the end and then have the culture name reflect this.  And pick up the proper resource file.  I have spent a lot of time researching and haven't found a way in .net core 3.1.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: I haven't done this but I think you may want to define a custom locale

Comment: I don't think it's possible by builtin i18n. If treat the states of US as individual cultures, there are too many provinces to handle in the world.

Comment: Thanks Aluan, and Donggas90.  Custom Locale is no longer possible in .net core.  I found through researching providing a custom resourcemanager I can override GetResxFileName which means I could attach my own file naming to retrieve the right file I believe.  But I don't get where I can use this with the startup.cs in respects to setting up localization. Trying to figure out where I can use my resource manager globally and overrides that to get he appropriate file.  Any thoughts?